# How to determine the size of (all the content) a file so I can allocate memory for it at once?

Tags: c, file, size, calloc

I am trying to allocate memory for the content of a file with words(separated by: \n).

How do I replace the 16000 to make it usable with files of greater size?

My code:

```
typedef struct node {
    bool is_word;
    struct node* children[27];
} node;

node* root;


bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(dictionary, "rb");


    node* node_bucket = calloc(16000, sizeof(node));
    node* next_free_node = node_bucket;

    // compute...

    // to later free the memory with another function
    root = node_bucket;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think the most portable way is to use [`ftell()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftell). That will require you to seek around in the file first to go to the end though, which probably isn't optimal performance-wise. On POSIX, you can use `fstat()` to ask the file system instead.

Comment: @user3419211 Do you want the exact number of bytes stored in a file excluding the character '\n'.

Comment: including the "\n"! I used ftell() as unwind suggested and it seems to be working.

Comment: How can i check if it is working? Is there a way to check the size of allocated memory?

Comment: @user3419211 youz cannot check the size of allocated memory. It's pointless anyway. If you allocate 1000 bytes, then you already know that the size is 1000 bytes.

Comment: Why don't you use a dynamic approach and allocate a child when needed?

Comment: I did this to get a higher speed

Comment: You check it worked with `if (fp == NULL)` and then with `if (node_bucket == NULL)`. Always check the return value from file opening and from the `malloc` family. You might think it should always work, but this may be your first warning that you have a memory leak, or are asking for more than is available.

Comment: @unwind *I think the most portable way is to use ftell() ...*  Actually, for a file opened in binary mode that's technically undefined behavior, assuming the use of `fseek(..., SEEK_END)`.  **7.21.9.2  The
`fseek`
function**: *A binary stream need not
meaningfully support
`fseek`
calls with a
`whence`
value of `SEEK_END`.* and footnote 268:  *Setting  the  file  position  indicator  to  end-of-file,  as  with
`fseek(file,  0,  SEEK_END)`,  has undefined behavior for a binary stream ...*

Comment: At the end Im assigning node_bucket to root. this is preventing me from freeing and returns: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fe9ac9d2018 ***

Comment: @AndrewHenle are sure you didn't mixup the terms _binary stream_ and _binary file_ ? Why should `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)` on a binary _file_ be UB ? The size of an existing _file_ is known so we can `fseek`to any position of the file.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Per the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) **7.21.5.3 The `fopen` function**:  *The `fopen` function opens the file whose name is the string pointed to by
`filename`, and associates a stream with it. The argument `mode`
points to a string.  If the string is one of the following, the file is
open in the indicated mode. ...*  Are you saying opening a file in binary mode results in anything other than a binary stream?  Note that the "size of a file" is implementation-dependent.  There is no implementation-independent way to determine that.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  For example:  http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB27U_6.2.0/com.ibm.zos.r12.cbcpx01/ossbin.htm%23ossbin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allocate memory dynamically without knowing how large the file is. I used a block size that is a power of 2, which is generally kinder towards block I/O. It wastes a little when the last block is only partially used, but here is an example, which you could adapt to work with your node structs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE 16384

int main(void) {
    unsigned char *buf = NULL;
    unsigned char *tmp = NULL;
    size_t totalread = 0;
    size_t currentsize = 0;
    size_t currentread = 0;
    FILE *fp;

    if((fp = fopen("test.txt", "rb")) == NULL)
        exit(1);
    do {
        currentsize += BLOCKSIZE;
        if((tmp = realloc(buf, currentsize)) == NULL)
            exit(1);
        buf = tmp;
        currentread = fread( &buf[totalread], 1, BLOCKSIZE, fp);
        totalread += currentread;
    } while (currentread == BLOCKSIZE);

    printf("Total size was %zu\n", totalread);
    free(buf);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach to get the size of a file is using [`ftell()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/):

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); // non-portable
long size = ftell(fp);
```

However, as the comment says, this is not portable, because N1570 documents in "7.21.9.2 The seek function":

> 2 ...... A binary stream need not meaningfully support fseek calls with a
>   whence value of SEEK_END.

Alternatively, you can write a function to get the size of a file on your own:

```
size_t fSize(FILE *fp)
{
    void *ptr = malloc(1);
    size_t size = 0;
    while(fread(ptr, 1, 1, fp) == 1)
        size++;
    if(feof(fp))
        return size;
    else
        return 0; // reading error
}
```

An accuracy-efficiency trade-off:

```
size_t fRoughSize(FILE *fp)
{
    void *ptr = malloc(1024);
    size_t size = 0;
    while(fread(ptr, 1024, 1, fp) == 1024)
        size += 1024;
    if(feof(fp))
        return size;
    else
        return 0; // reading error
}
```